# Overriding Ace Editor defaults through CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, keyboard-shortcuts, ace-editor

I have an Ace Text Editor enabled input field. I am attempting to execute an action through the keyboard shortcut combination of Shift+Enter, which is handled in my CoffeeScript file. Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug that Shift+Enter is automatically entering a newline character (presumably because defaults from Ace are not being overwritten). I would like the CoffeeScript keyboard shortcut to take precedence. Can someone point me in the right direction of how I could approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() from coffeescript handler to not allow the event to reach ace or use handler in ace like: `editor.commands.bindKey("Shift-Enter", function() {...})`